# Is there a way to use arrowkeys(up & down) to focus my search result?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to get the same functionality as the search modal in kit.sveltekit.dev when you press cmd + k

Here I use my up and down keys to quickly go through them

[image]

What I have now is an input that shows searchresult when I type and I can't figure out a way to use my arrow key to cycle through them

```
<script>
  export let apps;
  let searchTerm;

  let filteredApps = [];
  $: filteredApps = apps.filter((app) => {
    let appName = app.app_name.toLowerCase();
    return appName.includes(searchTerm);
  });
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" bind:value={searchTerm} />
  <div>
    <ul>
      {#each filteredApps as app}
        <li>
          <a href={app.app_name}>{app.app_name} </a>
        </li>
      {/each}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the same functionality I'd suggest looking at how they implemented it. You can find code for their search [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/blob/master/sites/kit.svelte.dev/src/lib/search/SearchBox.svelte). Specifically this part for their modal, starting around line 135. Their code is pretty easy to read.

They attach on:keydown event listener on their modal element. The function it triggers checks to see if event.key equals ArrowDown or ArrowUp and cycles accordingly.

Comment: link is gone, they refactored some code it seem to ... ?

Comment: change the branch/tag from 'master' to '@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0', you will see code.